# ImportError: No module named ... (but I have __init__.py files and have set PYTHONPATH)

Tags: python

I know this question is asked over and over, but looking at all the similar questions here I cannot seem to find any answers that are much different that what I have already tried... Apologies if this really is a duplicate.

I have a simple python package that have written called "clam". But when I try to import a module from it, I get the ImportError: no module named ... error.

But if I directly import the module I do not get an error:

```
import libClam  <-- this works.
```

I have looked at a number of similar questions here to see what I am doing wrong but they all seem to suggest doing what I have already done (set my PYTHONPATH to point to the parent directory of the module I am trying to import AND to add an empty file named:

`__init__.py`

that lives in that directory).  I have also poured over this page:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

(specifically the section 6.4 Packages)

Here is a short output from my shell:

```
bvz@manjaro-xps15:~/Documents/dev/clam$ pwd
/home/bvz/Documents/dev/clam

bvz@manjaro-xps15:~/Documents/dev/clam$ ls -l
total 56
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bvz users   348 Apr  7 14:48 clamError.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bvz users   769 Apr  7 14:48 clamError.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 bvz users     0 Apr 10 22:23 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bvz users   127 Apr  3 20:10 __init__.pyc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bvz users  7782 Apr 10 22:32 libClam.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bvz users  7006 Apr 10 22:32 libClam.pyc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bvz users 13602 Apr 10 19:06 libClarisse.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 bvz users 11585 Apr 10 22:19 libClarisse.pyc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bvz users     0 Apr  7 12:28 parking.py

bvz@manjaro-xps15:~/Documents/dev/clam$ cat __init__.py

bvz@manjaro-xps15:~/Documents/dev/clam$ env | grep PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=/home/bvz/Documents/dev/squirrel:/home/bvz/Documents/dev/clam:

bvz@manjaro-xps15:~/Documents/dev/clam$ python2
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jan 10 2019, 23:20:52) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/bvz/Documents/dev/squirrel', '/home/bvz/Documents/dev/clam', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py2.7.egg']
>>> import clam.libClam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named clam.libClam
>>> from clam import libClam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named clam
>>> import libClam
>>>
```

Notice the last line where the simple statement:

```
import libClam
```

works.  So apparently I have successfully set my PYTHONPATH, but somehow it does not recognize the parent directory as a package.

python 3.7 is the default installation on this machine (i.e. if I type 'python' I get a python 3.7 session). But this code needs to run in a DCC package that is still limited to python 2.7.  Could that be part of the issue?

I am sorry for the very basic nature of this question, but even trying to do all of my due diligence and research I am coming up with a blank. Thanks.

Comment: You have to add the *parent folder* of your package to your PYTHONPATH. `PYTHONPATH=/home/bvz/Documents/dev:`

Comment: you'd need to have the parent directory of `clam` in your `PYTHONPATH`; i.e. `/home/bvz/Documents/dev`.

Comment: So if I do this, it should work? (it doesn't but I may be doing something wrong):  If I keep my PYTHONPATH=/home/bvz/Documents/dev/clam but move all of the files in it (including __init__.py) to a sub-dir named "modules"... should that work?

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. What I just posted still won't work because I would need to say: from modules import libClam...  I think I understand now.  I will have to modify my PYTHONPATH to point to the parent directory like you both suggested.  I think I have to figure out the best way to manage my various paths, but till then this solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Imports should be relative to the directory you run Python from. Since your current working directory is already inside `clam`, you should not include it in your import. Instead, do:

```
import libClam
```

Comment: This solves the immediate issue in the way I was running the example, but the bigger picture is that my PYTHONPATH needs to point to the parent directory. As far as I understand, simply changing my import statement to 'import libClam' is not something that will easily scale.